How to serialize into a specific format
Using YamlDotNet, how to serialize a byte[] like that [49,20,50]?
The yaml file I need is:
    device:
      name: device1
      key: [49,20,50]

I have tried:

Defined the key as byte[], however, the yaml looks like it:

    device:
      name: device1
      key: 
        - 49
        - 20
        - 50


Defined the key as string and create an IYamlTypeConverter that is using $"[ {string.Join(",", bytes.ToArray())} ]" to convert it, however, the key is created between single quote
'. The yaml looks like it:

    device:
      name: device1
      key: '[49,20,50]'

My model is:
    public class device
    {
       public string name{ get; set; }
       public string key{ get; set; } OR public byte[] key{ get; set; } 
    }

Thanks

What you want is called "FlowStyle" and the docs describe how to get it:
YamlDotNet Documentation
Disclaimer: All following examples are 1:1 copies from above linked documentation! (Copied here to avoid "link-only" answer / avoid dead link)
The example is for integer sequences. You need to declare an event emitter:
class FlowStyleIntegerSequences : ChainedEventEmitter
{
    public FlowStyleIntegerSequences(IEventEmitter nextEmitter)
        : base(nextEmitter) {}

    public override void Emit(SequenceStartEventInfo eventInfo, IEmitter emitter)
    {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable<int>).IsAssignableFrom(eventInfo.Source.Type))
        {
            eventInfo = new SequenceStartEventInfo(eventInfo.Source)
            {
                Style = SequenceStyle.Flow
            };
        }

        nextEmitter.Emit(eventInfo, emitter);
    }
}

and then use it:
var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
    .WithEventEmitter(next => new FlowStyleIntegerSequences(next))
    .Build();

serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new {
    strings = new[] { "one", "two", "three" },
    ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
});

produces
strings:
- one
- two
- three
ints: [1, 2, 3]

